# I get the unused argument error every time I run this code, why?

Tags: r, dplyr

Can you please help me with finding out what is wrong with my code. I am using the mutate function to add a column and map certain IDs under different categories based on some condition. Below is my code

```
 Repeat_Query2 = Repeat_Query %>% mutate(Category = ifelse(Queries = 2 & Conversion > 0 & Conversion <= 33, "LQ-LC", ifelse(Queries > 2 & Queries <= 4 & Conversion > 0 & Conversion <= 33, "MQ-LC", ifelse(Queries > 4 & Conversion > 0 & Conversion <= 33, "HQ-LC", ifelse(Queries = 2 & Conversion >= 33 & Conversion <= 66, "LQ-MC", ifelse(Queries > 2 & Queries <= 4 & Conversion >= 33 & Conversion <= 66, "MQ-MC", ifelse(Queries > 4 & Conversion >= 33 & Conversion <= 66, "HQ-MC", ifelse(Queries = 2 & Conversion >= 66, "LQ-HC", ifelse(Queries > 2 & Queries <= 4 & Conversion >= 66, "MQ-HC", ifelse(Queries > 4 & Conversion >= 66, "HQ-HC","NA"))))))))))
```

Comment: This is a great place to use `dplyr::case_when` instead of many nested ifelse statements, which is very hard to read / understand / debug.

Comment: Provide example data, from a quick look the code doesn't seem to have syntax errors. You could have a more readable code if you use `case_when` or `cut` instead of nested `ifelse` hell.

Comment: If you get an error message, it is important to show it verbatim. If you can't infer from the error message, where exactly the error occurs (often you can), you can try using `traceback()`.

Answer (score 1):

I am learning `case_when` and put the comments from others together:

```
Repeat_Query2 = Repeat_Query %>% 
  mutate(Category = case_when(Queries == 2 & Conversion > 0 & Conversion <= 33 ~ "LQ-LC", 
                  Queries > 2 & Queries <= 4 & Conversion > 0 & Conversion <= 33 ~ "MQ-LC", 
                  Queries > 4 & Conversion > 0 & Conversion <= 33 ~ "HQ-LC",  
                  Queries == 2 & Conversion >= 33 & Conversion <= 66 ~ "LQ-MC", 
                  Queries > 2 & Queries <= 4 & Conversion >= 33 & Conversion <= 66 ~ "MQ-MC", 
                  Queries > 4 & Conversion >= 33 & Conversion <= 66 ~ "HQ-MC", 
                  Queries == 2 & Conversion >= 66 ~ "LQ-HC", 
                  Queries > 2 & Queries <= 4 & Conversion >= 66 ~ "MQ-HC", 
                  Queries > 4 & Conversion >= 66 ~ "HQ-HC",
                  TRUE ~ NA))
```

This may still not work. If you get an error message, providing some data and details would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `=` instead of `==` as an operator. `=` is for assignment and function arguments and `==` is for logical operations. Also, as others here have said, you should use `case_when()` here.

You get the error, because for example `Queries` is interpreted as an argument.